# Data Set for Recommender System that contains contextual aspect-level ratings (as well as reviews)

Tags: data-request, research

I am looking for a data set for building a recommender system that takes into account **contextual aspect-level ratings**.

For example, a data set from Tripadvisor would be great if it contained "traveler type" (like business or family) and "time of year" (like Jun-Aug) (as **contexts**) as well as **aspect**-level ratings (like "Rooms" and "Cleanliness" and so on).

What I want to check is, if **recommendation accuracy** can be improved by incorporating **contextual aspect-level** ratings as I expect recommendations to be more accurate in this case than when e.g. only aspect-level ratings/only context/just overall ratings is/are used.

Any other data set from any other domain in which the approach would be useful is appreciated, too. It would be a plus, if the data set also contained text-based reviews.

Thank you for your time!